# Изменить код в теге <script> и выполнить

Tags: javascript

Необходимо программными средствами изменить содержание тега `<script>`, а затем выполнить новый код.
Ничего на ум не приходит, как удалить его и вставить в документ заново.

*Например:*

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var script = document.querySelector('script');
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.innerHTML = "document.write('document');"
  script.parentElement.replaceChild(newScript, script);
});
```

```html
<button>run new code</button>
<script>
  console.log('concole')
</script>
```

Есть ли еще методы сделать подобное?

Comment: Ничего на ум не приходит, как зачем?

Comment: @Other, ну тут все упрощенно.... для выполнения кода в `iframe`. Допустим есть `textarea`  пишу в нем код, нажимаю на кнопочку -> он выполняется в `iframe`

Comment: Тогда только так, как Вы предложили. Блок был выполнен во время разбора документа при загрузке. Можно поизвращаться с `evil`, передавая внутрь строку кода, но это для мсье, которые знают толк в `eval`.